# Scrapy get text from function ()

Tags: scrapy

I want to get the branchId in function but couldnt. Do you have any idea about how to get from a function.

```
item["branchId"] = row.xpath('//div[@class="branchprofile"]//script/text()').extract()[0]
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="branchprofile">
<script>
(function(k,v){RMVH.ANALYTICS.DataLayer.pushKV(k,v);}('branch',{"branchId":5112345,"companyName":"KLM","brandName":"London KLM",,"pageType":"Standard"})); </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `re` method on the xpath and not `extract`. Extract will give just the text

```
item['branchId'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='branchprofile']/script/text()").re('branchId":\s*(\d+)')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your sample gave me a view of how to use regex. I have had multiple outputs and I wrote different regexes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@class` where you should be using `@id`:

```
>[1]: sel.xpath("//div[@id='branchprofile']/script/text()")[0].extract()
<[1]: '\n(function(k,v){RMVH.ANALYTICS.DataLayer.pushKV(k,v);}(\'branch\',{"branchId":5112345,"companyName":"KLM","brandName":"London KLM",,"pageType":"Standard"})); '
```